# How come condition of my IF affects global variable making function a loop

Tags: javascript

```
 var i = 0
 function bumBum() {
  if (++i == 12){
    console.log("fin");
    i = 0;
  }else{
    console.log(i);
    bumBum();
  }

 }
 bumBum();
```

Was going through some code and saw a bit like this one, i think i'm missing something basic but i just can't understand why (and if it is the case) ++i affects global i.

Comment: That's how JavaScript works. It's called closure. Yes, you are missing something basic. :-)

Comment: Are you asking what `++i` is? [increment prefix operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)

Comment: What do you mean by global i? there is only one i declared at the top.

Comment: Oh i see, im just dumb and didnt quite understood what increment is.

Comment: What other variable would `++i` affect?

Comment: if you want the same recursion without the global `i`, you instead use a parameter.    https://jsfiddle.net/zo0p39gt/  This has the same effect without relying on a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

In JS all variables are global by default, unless you specify `var` keyword inside other scope. So that means increment for `i` (by doing `++i`) WILL affect `var i = 0`. If you want it to not affect global variable specify `var i` inside `bumBum` function.

About `++i`

`++i == 12` mean increment i by 1 (same as `i = i+1;` or `i += 1;`) first and than compare it with 12

`i++` mean compare it to 12 first and than increment i

`i--` is same as `i -= 1`

`++i == 12` is not same as `i + 1 == 12`

Comment: Specifying `var i` inside `bumBum` will result in an infinite loop, so I doubt if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: I just didnt know that increment returns i+1 value, i thought it is the same as for example  if ((i + 1) == 12), evaluated but does not change i. As i said im just dumb and thought i knew what increment is.